# highcharts xAxis density

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in my jsp.

With the help of Highcharts, usually we can make a chart with all points equally spaced in the x-axis.

Here I want to set the points NOT splaced in the x-axis, but by the x values.

e.g.

usually plot `[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]`, chart shows [point]-[point]-[point]

I want to plot `[1,1],[3,1],[7,1]` like [point]--[point]----[point]

where "-" stands for the distance between points.

Can you please show me a example with javascript like `$('#mycontainer').highcharts(???);`

Comment: The example at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/ expressed my exact problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You do that just like you did `[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]`. Here is a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kza88bug/) using monthly categorized xAxis and the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 60,
            x: -60
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[1,1],[3,1],[7,1]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified my question. The xAxis data are not simple integer, but datetime. Currently I found a example which meets my need. Thanks anyway!